# JSF: c:set on button click?

Tags: jsf, redirect, button, javabeans, backing-beans

Is it possible to "execute"/"render" various `c:set` tags when a certain button is pressed and a redirect will occure?

I dont want to set the properties of the backing bean code-wise, for im filling them with static data. As im not talking about one single button here but about multiple ones, doing this code-wise would produce lots of boilerplated code. Thats the reason why I want to use `c:set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<c:set>` is the wrong tool for the job you had in mind and therefore insuitable. It doesn't run during submitting the form, but during building the view.

Use [`<f:setPropertyActionListener>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html) instead. E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.property1}" value="value1" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.property2}" value="value2" />
</h:commandButton>
```

---

A completely different alternative is to just send request parameters by `<f:param>`. This allows you creating bookmarkable links which is much better for user experience and SEO.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)